# Widget from Angular 2 app webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, requirejs

If it is unclear than let's try this again.

In my research I learned that some call it a micro-loader, which is what I am trying to achieve. In the webpack configuration I have this in the plugin section

```
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'src/index.html',
    title: METADATA.title,
    chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
    metadata: METADATA,
    inject: 'head'
  }),
```

which turns an html file without any script tags (or even placeholders for them) during compilation in something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>My angular widget</title>

  <meta name="description" content="My angular widget">

  <!-- base url -->
  <base href="/">


<link href="main.23ca1423b5f74b9e7d3a76e9eed69f71.css" rel="stylesheet"><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.60dbe827b1b8353af66f.bundle.js" defer></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.0f040ba30b8e909c6a82.bundle.js" defer></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.d6e9175158901f87b307.bundle.js" defer></script></head>

<body>

  <app class="skin-green gbp">
    Loading...
  </app>




</body>
</html>
```

It magically adds those 4 files (1 css, 3 js) into the head section.

Now what I want is something like this (the  angular-widget.js file)

```
function loadCss(url) {
    var link = document.createElement("link");
    link.type = "text/css";
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.href = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
}

loadCss('https://my-domain.com/app/main.1928b5b43a58428e7798d12176de68e3.css');

require(['https://my-domain.com/app/polyfills.60dbe827b1b8353af66f.bundle.js'], function() {
    require(['https://my-domain.com/app/vendor.623bbcbf99de3526eab8.bundle.js'], function() {
        require(['https://my-domain.com/app/main.d4f6aea1525a044b41da.bundle.js'], function() {
        });
    });
});
```

Which is a file I came up which does what I want it to do, but takes manual work everytime and utilizes require.js for now (but can be anything, I don't really care), which is the only point of entry and gets automatically generated during the compilation so I don't have to manually change the hashes everytime something changes and gets redeployed.

-- Old Post starts here

I have an angular 2 project using webpack for compiling. But I do not want the entry point to be the index.html, because the app is to be embeded into another webpage, which I do not have full control over.

I am trying to find a way to output something similar to the index.html but inside a .js file which I than can include on the webpage.

www.some-domain.com/webpage

```
[...]
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://my-domain.com/angular-widget.js"></script>
<app>
    Loading...
</app>
[...]
```

Is there a way to generate that `angular-widget.js` during the webpack process? I tried to hijack the HtmlWebpackPlugin, but that expects to output HTML. I am fairly new to the whole webpack process, but my approach right now would be some template where I just can output the different files which are produced by webpack, for example using require.js. But maybe the whole thing is even possible only via webpack?